# Get IDs of deleted entries

Tags: add-on-development, extension, hook

I’m creating an ExpressionEngine extension. I want to get the IDs of any records that are deleted. I’m aware of the `delete_entries_end()` and `delete_entries_loop()` hooks, but they both return `void` which isn’t much use.

Is this possible out of the box with ExpressionEngine? I wanted to steer away from editing core files to make any future core upgrades seamless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[delete_entries_loop](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/api/channel_entries/index.html#delete-entries-loop) passes two arguments: `$val` (which is the `entry_id` of the entry which has just been deleted) and `$channel_id`. So, your `entry_id` is there for the taking.

But if you want to get this data *before* each entry is deleted, then you are out of luck, as the hook is triggered right *after* each entry is deleted.

Comment: So if I set up my extension like this (https://gist.github.com/martinbean/6f99579de42e77d8a087) then the first parameter passed to my `on_delete_entries` method will be the ID of the entry that was deleted?

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: That’s great. Thanks for your speedy response!